# Webpack HMR breaks on parse error

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-hmr

I am having issues with my code not reloading with HMR. I am using the CLI webpack dev server.  The changes are seen and webpack recompiles but the site does not reload.

Console log:

```
[Log] [WDS] Hot Module Replacement enabled.
[Log] [WDS] App updated. Recompiling... (x2)
[Log] [WDS] App hot update...
[Log] [HMR] Checking for updates on the server...
[Warning] [HMR] Update failed: parse@[native code]
onreadystatechange@http://localhost:8080/assets/vendor.js:67:38
```

This error is part of the injected Webpack code:

```
request.onreadystatechange = function() {
     ...
  var update = JSON.parse(request.responseText); <-- this breaks
```

My code is basically this: https://github.com/jaredpalmer/react-production-starter except that I switched it to Koa2. Along the way I was unable to use build in HMR for a variety of reasons so now am resorting to the external server.

My config:

```
{
  devtool: 'eval',
  entry: {
    main: [
     path.join(process.cwd(), 'client'),
    ],
    vendor: [
      'react',
      'react-dom',
      'react-router',
      'redux',
      'react-redux',
      'aphrodite'
    ]
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    chunkFilename: '[name].chunk.js',
    publicPath: '/assets/',
    path: path.join(process.cwd(), 'public/assets')
  },
  module: {

    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel',
        exclude: /(node_modules|server)/,
        query: {
          cacheDirectory: false,
          presets: ["es2015", "react", "stage-0"]
        }
      },
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('development'),
      '__DEV__': true
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin('vendor', 'vendor.js', 2),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin()
  ],
}
```

I call the webpack server with:

```
webpack-dev-server --config tools/webpack.client.dev.js --hot --inline
```

What could be the issue? It appears that webpack is receiving invalid info to parse but I have no idea what that is supposed to be or coming from.

The client index.js file same as [here](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/react-production-starter/blob/master/client/index.js).

I have rearranged the code that delivers the initial render but its very similar. Here's the original [server code](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/react-production-starter/blob/master/server/index.js). Primarily I have turned it into a catch-all route `router.all('*')` and changed the html a bit but for the most part its the same. Here are the script tags:

```
 <script>window.renderedClassNames = ${JSON.stringify(data.css.renderedClassNames)};</script>
 <script>window.INITIAL_STATE = ${JSON.stringify(initialState)};</script>
 <script src="${ env === 'production' ? '/assets/vendor.js' : 'http://localhost:8080/assets/vendor.js'}" ></script>
 <script async src="${ env === 'production' ? '/assets/main.js' : 'http://localhost:8080/assets/main.js'}" ></script>
```

The `client/index.js` file contains this at the bottom:

```
if (module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept('../common/routes/root', () => {
    unsubscribeHistory()
   setTimeout(render)
  })
 }
```

It is however never called.

Can someone shed a light?